# How to use CSS on an Html.ActionLink in C#

Tags: c#, css, asp.net-mvc, html.actionlink

I tried this code

`<%: Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home", new { @class = "NavLink" })%>`

and it links to the css so that I can style the link, but it changes the link to have a different URL that is not to my controller like it is without the `new { @class = "NavLink" }`. Is there any way to let me style these links without ruining my URLs so they go to the correct pages?

Thanks!

Comment: linked question is VB.NET, this is C#, so not quite an exact duplicate

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Make sure you are using the [proper overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd504972.aspx):

```
<%: Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home", null, new { @class = "NavLink" })%>
                                              ^                ^
                                          routeValues    htmlAttributes
```

Answer (score 1):

Method Actionlink have some overloading.

If you want to determine some html attributes, you should use such methods(in your case):

```
  ActionLink(HtmlHelper, String, String, RouteValueDictionary, IDictionary<String, Object>)
  ActionLink(HtmlHelper, String, String, String, Object, Object)
  ActionLink(HtmlHelper, String, String, String, RouteValueDictionary, IDictionary<String, Object>)
```

More about this here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.linkextensions.actionlink.aspx